# what necessary requirements to support the arcore in a android phone

Tags: android-camera, requirements, arcore

If i have a android phone. and i want to know if my phone support ARCORE?
Is there any requests necessary ?
Such as the fps of the camera、 size of images 、Android version and so on.
I want to get some specific requirements to assess whether or not it is supported.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ARCore currently has a specific set of devices that it supports:

https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/#supported_devices

Within your application, you can use the `ArCoreApk` API provided to check whether the current device supports ARCore:

https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/ArCoreApk

The ARCore sample applications provide a good example of how to use this API:

https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/hello_ar_java/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/core/examples/java/helloar/HelloArActivity.java#L118